# scrape a specific div value with beautifulsoup in nested div

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I currently try scrape a value at this specific website for a school project https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=53706%20income&tid=ACSST5Y2020.S1901
it's the first one below if you search Median income (dollars), which should be the median income of the area, the comp-id keep changing for some reason[image]

[This median income estimate is what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU7rV.png)

I tried serveral method on the sites to go over the nested divs but I'm not able to get any results after runned, below is a code that I tried to use, but it just kept returning nothing to me.
Any help will be appreciate, thanks!

```
import csv
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 



DRIVER_PATH = 'chromedriver_107.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)


            url = 'https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=' + '53706' + '%20income&tid=ACSST5Y2020.S1901'
            driver.get(url)

            page = requests.get(url)


            content = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

            a = soup.findAll("div", {"comp-id":"1539"})
            print(a)
```

Comment: That page makes heavy use of javascript.  The problem might be that you haven't given it enough time to process all the javascript, and so that element hasn't yet been created when you look for it.

Comment: I think it automatically closes itself after a few second returning an empty [], is there any way to let it run longer?

Comment: If I open the page you said, and I search for comp-id = 1539 in the browser devtool does not appear anything, are you sure the link you shared is correct? Are there any other step missing to arrive to that element?

Comment: Oh i just realized that it changes each time, if you search median income (dollar) it should be the first one below

Comment: but i'm not getting any result if i search for the class type either...

Comment: But there are 2 URLs in your question, the one you put in the question and the one you are navigation with selenium. With selenium you are navigating to: `https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=53706%20income&tid=ACSST5Y2020.S1901` and in the post you are sharing url `https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=53703%20income&tid=ACSST5Y2020.S1901` What is the correct one? Can you share an screenshot of the element you are looking for?

Comment: Oh I think the difference is only the zipcode in the middle, right? actually i plan to scrape this information for different zipcodes so it would be very helpful if i can get a generic way to scrape this info, i'll post a screen shot in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#set up Chrome driver
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()


#Define web driver as a Chrome driver and navigate
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

url = 'https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=53703%20income&tid=ACSST5Y2020.S1901'
driver.get(url)

# We print the label of row 11 (Which is the median)
label = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@row-id='11'])[1]")))
print(label.text)
# We print the values of row 11 (Which is the median)
values = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@row-id='11'])[2]")))
print(values.text)
```

Output:

```
Median income (dollars)
42,153
±3,200
114,643
±28,572
139,694
```